# Pickling from multiple threads in Python

Tags: python, pickle

I have a python program with multiple threads.  Each thread detects events, which I would like to store somewhere so that I can read them in again (for testing).  Right now, I'm using Pickle to output the events, and each thread outputs to a different file.  Ideally, I would only use one output file, and all the threads would write to it, but when I try this, it looks like the various threads try to write their output at the same time, and they don't get pickled properly.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like a good place to use a [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html).

- Have all your event detection threads put items on a shared Queue.
- Create another thread to get items from the queue, and write/pickle/whatever from this thread.

from the Queue docs:

> "The Queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It
>   is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be
>   exchanged safely between multiple threads. The Queue class in this
>   module implements all the required locking semantics. It depends on
>   the availability of thread support in Python; see the threading
>   module."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with [threading.Lock()](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects) objects.
You create a lock before creating all your threads, you give it to the method that is responsible of saving/pickling items, and this method should acquire the lock before writing into the file and releasing it after.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [lock](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects) and acquire/release it around every call to `pickle.dump()`.

Answer (score 1):

The [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#module-logging) module has a `Rlock` built into its Handlers. So you could `logging` as normal (just create a handler to log to a file.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [threading.Lock()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects):

```
import threading
import pickle
picke_lock = threading.Lock()
   def do(s):
       picke_lock.acquire()
       try:
           ps = pickle.dumps(s)
       finally:
           picke_lock.release()
       return ps

t1 = threading.Thread(target=do, args =("foo",))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=do, args =("bar",))
p1 = t1.start()
p2 = t2.start()

inpt = raw_input('type anything and click enter... ')
```