# Updating Dictionary Using Background Process in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm writing a piece of code that has an object with a dictionary, and an Asyncio process that pulls data from a number of sources every few seconds. It then populates the dictionary with the new data.

The next thing I need to do is write a computationally intensive script which will read and perform computations based on the current state of the dictionary.

Ideally, I'd like to run the Asnycio process in the background, and re-populate the dictionary as data comes. This way the main process can do its computations on the most recent data without needing to wait for the data collection to complete.

I've read quite a bit about multithreading and multiprocessing, and I'm not sure which will help more. I'm guessing this is not a totally unheard of task I'm talking about. Any suggestions on the best way of doing this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Python 3.7+ if that helps. Thanks in advance!

Update: I've already written it as a multithreaded process, but have not yet built the second component I mentioned. I know that due to the GIL, since only one thread can run at a time this may mean there is no speed improvement.

Comment: There are some good suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514958/pickling-from-multiple-threads-in-python. You either need to implement a queue or locks for the read/write processes.